# Getting more information on Azure File share file handles - Get-AzStorageFileHandle

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files, process-explorer

I have got the open file handles from azure storage account file share, but this information seems to be very less to understand what Process has started it or On which file this file handle is.

Getting file handles https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstoragefilehandle?view=azps-2.7.0

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/master/src/Storage/Storage.Management/help/Get-AzStorageFileHandle.md#example-1-list-all-file-handles-on-a-file-share-recursively-and-sort-by-clientip-and-opentime

How to get more information using handleid or sessionid from this list?

I have searched a lot on azure docs as well as on internet but no information on this.

Sample script and response :

```
PS C:\>Get-AzStorageFileHandle -ShareName "mysharename" -Recursive | Sort-Object ClientIP,OpenTime 

HandleId    Path                  ClientIp       ClientPort OpenTime             LastReconnectTime FileId               ParentId             SessionId          
--------    ----                  --------       ---------- --------             ----------------- ------               --------             ---------          
28506980357                       104.46.105.229 49805      2019-07-29 08:37:36Z                   0                    0                    9297571480349046273
28506980537 dir1                  104.46.105.229 49805      2019-07-30 09:28:48Z                   10376363910205800448 0                    9297571480349046273
```

Comment: What more information you want to fetch?

Comment: @GauravMantri I want to understand what Process has started it or On which file that file handle is.

Comment: So far I have gone through 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4022301/azure-file-storage-connection-creation-performance-problems this article in which they say to use Handle.exe to verify the active handles opened against the Azure File share. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle)

But I am still out of clue about how to use process explorer (handle.exe) to view file handles  from azure file share

Comment: this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-windows-file-connection-problems#error-1816-not-enough-quota-is-available-to-process-this-command-when-you-copy-to-an-azure-file-share says to Reduce the number of concurrent open handles by closing some handles, and then retry. But before closing file handles I want to understand which process are having that file handles or on which file or directory that file handle is.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick research and local test, I believe 
 the "Path" returned by the command is the file or directory path you are looking for. 
File handle is not only for file but also for folder. 
The trick here is the handle for file is not being hold always. In fact, most applications release the file handle as soon as they open the file, like notepad. So when you run the command, for the most of time, you could only see handle for folder, not files.

To verify this, I've tested with the code below:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = args[0];
            var file=File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to release the handle");
            Console.ReadKey();
            file.Close();
        }
```

When excuting `File.Open`, the process holds handle, then I run `Get-AzStorageFileHandle`. The handle for "test.csv" is displayed:

[image]

But if you open the file with notepad, only handle for folder is displayed.

Anyway, you can use the "path" returned to determine which file is being held by others.

By the way, the handle.exe is not applied for cloud environment. You should not use it.